# Why does this not count CRLF at the end of a string?

Tags: regex, perl

I have this code which I hope will count the CRLFs at the end of the string.
It doesn't currently work and I can't see why.

```
printf "text is [%s]", $text;   # debug this
my $number = ( $text =~ /\R$/ );
sprintf "File has [%i] errant CRLFs at the EOF\n", $number;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. To persuade other people to help you it would be beneficial if you included some test data, the current output from the test data and the expected output.

Comment: Maybe you could try add `m` and `g` modifiers to your regexp? See [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers) for more information. In this way you can count multiple occurrences of `\R`  in `$text`

Comment: Your regexp only matches one \R at the end of the line, so I don't see how it would ever do any counting.

Comment: There's not even an attempt to count anything in that code. You simply check if the string contains a line-ending.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of problems. You need to use global match in order to find several matches. Also your regex just matches the last `\R`

So, for the regex, use this `m/\R(?=\R*$)/g`, that matches `\R` that must be followed by 0 or more `\R` and then the end of string.

Another problem is that this `my $number = ( $text =~ /\R$/ );` does not return the number of matches. It returns `1` if there is a match. You should use a while loop for that (with `g` flag for the regex)

Finally, the last line should be `printf` instead of `sprintf`:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $text = "ASD
ASD
ASD
ASD





";

printf "text is [%s]", $text;   # debug this

my $number = 0;
$number++ while $text =~ m/\R(?=\R*$)/g;
# # or use this instead:
# my $number = () = $text =~ m/\R(?=\R*$)/g;


printf "\n\nFile has [%i] errant CRLFs at the EOF\n", $number;
```

**Output:**

```
text is [ASD
ASD
ASD
ASD





]

File has [6] errant CRLFs at the EOF
```

Comment: Note: the number of matches is returned if you impose list context. So you could also use the idiom `$num_matches = () = $text =~ /..../`

Comment: True, I'll add that to the answer. Thanks